# Как удалить двойной параграф в PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как удалить двойной параграф в PHP?

Этот метод не работает:

```
preg_replace('/(\n){3,}/', '\n\n', $text);
```

Comment: Что для вас «двойной параграф»?

Answer (score 0):

Для всех систем:

```
preg_replace('/(' . PHP_EOL . '){3,}/', PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL, $text);
```

Для Unix систем:

```
preg_replace("/\n{3,}/", "\n\n", $text);
```

Для не Unix систем:

```
preg_replace("/(\r\n){3,}/", "\r\n\r\n", $text);
```

И строковые литералы, содержащие эскейп-последовательности, нужно заключать в двойные кавычки.

Comment: все равно не работает

Comment: двойное экранирование знака должно быть `\\\`